# Can't load JSON content because of GCD

Tags: swift

App is project number 7 from Hacking with swift "Showing some JSON".

Because i have to filtrate through the results i have to made two arrays that store same JSON data.

```
 var petitions = [Petition]()
 var filtrated = [Petition] ()
```

There is a purple warning problem when i added `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async{` to `viewDidLoad()`

```swift
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var petitions = [Petition]()
    var filtrated = [Petition] ()
    
       
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem (title: "Filter", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(resenje))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self, action: #selector(refresh))// ili samo  #selector(webView.reload)
        
        let urlString : String
        if navigationController?.tabBarItem.tag == 0 {
            urlString = "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/petitions-1.json"
        } else {
            urlString = "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/petitions-2.json"
        }
       
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async{ [self] in
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
                parse(json: data)
               filtrated = petitions
                                return
        }
    }

    func parse(json: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let jsonPetitions = try? decoder.decode(Petitions.self, from: json){
            petitions = jsonPetitions.results
           
          
            
            tableView?.reloadData() //error:UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only
```

Program will work but it shows error alert I made and tableView is empty

[image: better view on code with warnings]

Comment: I’m shocked that Paul suggests synchronous `Data(contentsOf:`. Actually this is strongly discouraged even on a background thread. Use always asynchronous API to load data from a remote URL.

Comment: I'm still not on that level of knowledge that i can fully understand you but i will keep that in mind for my future work so i hope it will make sense to me @vadian

Comment: The `URLSession` approach is just as simple, but is _much_ better (e.g. if there is an error, you get critical diagnostic information; it opens up the door to support cancelation at some future date; it doesn’t block a worker thread like the synchronous `Data(contentsOf:)` pattern does; etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GCD `global` queue runs on a background thread. But all UI updates must take place on the main thread. As an aside, you also do not want a background thread to update properties, such as `filtrated`. So you will want to dispatch both the model and UI updates back to the main thread.

So, fetch and parse the data, and then dispatch the updates to the main queue:

```swift
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [self] in
    guard
        let url = URL(string: urlString),
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
        let responseObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Petitions.self, from: data)
    else {
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        filtrated = responseObject.results
        tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Or, better, use `URLSession`. And do not use `try?`, because if it fails, you are throwing away the `Error` object that provides crucial diagnostic information:

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { 
    print("Invalid url: \(urlString)")
    return
}

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [self] data, response, error in
    guard let data = data else {
        print("Request failed:", error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    do {
        let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(Petitions.self, from: data)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            filtrated = responseObject.results
            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    } catch let parsingError {
        print("Parsing failed:", parsingError)
        return
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: I came back to this question now and I have one question, i don't know is it important but anyway. Which .dataTask is used here for URLSession? dataTask(with Request:) or dataTask(with url:)? Or it's not important at all?

Comment: It doesn’t matter. As such, we often use the `URL` rendition (which saves us the extra step of manually creating a `URLRequest`) unless there is some customization of a `URLRequest` that is needed (e.g., we’re creating a `POST` request, custom headers, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You need to head back to the main thread to update the UI

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.tableView?.reloadData()
}
```